# Issue with reflecting messages from Telegram bot to Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, telegram-bot

I have a bot deployed on Heroku and it works pretty well (I use webhook to keep it updated).
I wanted to add some recording stuff (by reflecting all messages that come to the bot in the google spreadsheet), found a good script for it (https://github.com/MeneerOom/Connect-Telegram-Bot-to-Google-Sheets), tested it and faced with an issue - as soon as I turn the gs script on, the one I have in the bot's code stops working. I assume this is due to both scripts use webhooks and those somehow conflicting with each other, but I'm not really sure and would appreciate for some guidance here, whether my assumption is correct and how can it be fixed (if there is a way).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have only a single endpoint for Webhooks. Who was the last one - only that will work. So, in your case - you need to write that both logic in one script on Heroku.

Comment: thank you very much for the comment, it does clarify a lot. So, then, the logic to achieve what I need would be to place the whole code (including the part for recording the messages in the google sheet) into bot's script and deploy it on Heroku with just one webhook being used, correct?

Comment: Yes, one webserver on Heroku that listens to webhooks and manages how to respond on it.